# Setting LDAP Configuration in IBM Websphere Message Broker

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I'm a newbe for message broker.

I'm trying to create webservice security in message broker authenticated using LDAP.

but the authentication is always fail in my SOAP message header I have specify the right user: wpsadmin and right password : 123

this is my ldap configuration:
Quote:

```
mqsicreateconfigurableservice WBRK61_DEFAULT_BROKER -c SecurityProfiles -o LDAP -n authentication,authorization,propagation,authenticationConfig,authorizationConfig -v "LDAP,LDAP,TRUE,\"ldap://192.168.0.138:389/dc=hanoman, dc=co, dc=id\""
```

I'm not sure that my configuration is true or false. but the configuration below used by us for our websphere process server (Secure administration->applications, and infrastructure -> Standalone LDAP registry) .

Code:

```
Host   : 192.168.0.138
Port : 389
Base distinguished name (DN)  : dc=hanoman, dc=co, dc=id
Bind distinguished name (DN) : cn=wpsadmin, cn=users, dc=hanoman, dc=co, dc=id
```

I need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your initial bind is failing. Have you used mqsisetdbparms to set the user to use for search as described in http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fap04121_.htm

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `security profile` from the `Explorer->Broker->yourBroker` then right click on it.
2. Click on `Security Profiles ->Click on ADD` then Fill The Form with LDAP Attributes
3. Set LDAP Binding with `mqsisetdbparms` command.

For more assistance this link provides an excellent guide, it talks about WebSphere Message Broker 7 but it helped me to bind IBM Integration bus 9.0 [ Broker ] with LDAP 
This is the Link [Implemeting Message Flow Security in WebSphere Message Broker V7.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1002_fan/1002_fan.html)